# VBA to switch between 2 open PComm sessions

Tags: vba

I have been writing some VBA scripts to perform actions in PComm sessions.
For my latest one the process is to have 2 sessions open, both logged in to a different/separate (sub)system.
I'm trying to find out how to make VBA:
- Connect to 1 session
- Check if that session has specific values in specific coordinates (i can use the GetText command for this)
- If it is not the session, switch to the next open session and loop
- If it is the session, continue with the rest of the process (exit sub)

EDIT:
i've got the following code which helps determine if the correct subsystem is open.

```
Sub FindSession(FindPlatform As Platform)
Dim SessionLetter As String
Dim strSendToPlatform As String
Dim SL As Integer
Dim Timer As Date
Const DelayInterval = "00:01:00"

On Error GoTo Inicio
Inicio:
    Select Case FindPlatform

        Case 1
        strSendToPlatform = "CARE"

        Case 2
        strSendToPlatform = "GlobStar"

        Case 3
        strSendToPlatform = "MainFrame"

        Case 4
        strSendToPlatform = "Citsob"

        Case 5
        strSendToPlatform = "Cas"

        Case 6
        strSendToPlatform = "IMS"

    End Select

For SL = 1 To 7

If SL = 1 Then SessionLetter = "A"
If SL = 2 Then SessionLetter = "B"
If SL = 3 Then SessionLetter = "C"
If SL = 4 Then SessionLetter = "D"
If SL = 5 Then SessionLetter = "E"
If SL = 6 Then SessionLetter = "F"
If SL = 7 Then SessionLetter = "G"

Set sConnmgr = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnmgr")


Set objwcc = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")
objwcc.SetConnectionByName SessionLetter
    Select Case FindPlatform

        Case 1 'CARE
            If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 65, 3) = "AC2" Then
                SessionNotFound = False
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Set objwcc = Nothing
            End If

        Case 2 'GlobStar
            If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 29, 9) = "GLOBESTAR" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 26, 9) = "GLOBESTAR" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 26, 8) = "AMERICAN" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 25, 8) = "AMERICAN" Then
                SessionNotFound = False
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Set objwcc = Nothing
            End If

        Case 3 'MainFrame
            If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(2, 4, 5) <> "     " And objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(2, 4, 5) = "USS10" Then
                SessionNotFound = False
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Set objwcc = Nothing
            End If

        Case 4 'Citsob
            If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 2, 8) = "FASBRSCR" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 2, 7) = "FASAUTH" Then
                SessionNotFound = False
                Do While GetString(1, 2, 8) <> "FASBRSCR"
                SendString "", 1, 9, True
                Loop
            Exit Sub
            Else
                Set objwcc = Nothing
            End If

        Case 5 'Cas
            If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(3, 18, 18) = "CARDMEMBER SERVICE" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(3, 22, 3) = "CUR" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(2, 18, 18) = "CARDMEMBER SERVICE" Then
                SessionNotFound = False
            Exit Sub
            Else
                Set objwcc = Nothing
            End If

        Case 6 'IMS
        If objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(1, 2, 5) = "WNSPC" Or objwcc.autECLPS.GetText(7, 24, 7) = "SPECIAL" Then
            SessionNotFound = False
        Exit Sub
        Else
            Set objwcc = Nothing
        End If

    End Select

Next SL
```

It does check all my open sessions to see if the correct system is open, but it doesn't select that session to work in that.
For example, i was logged into the 'CARE' system and 'Globstar' system, and had 'CARE' as the active window. I had the VBA look for 'Globstar', which it did find, but it then continued to send commands to the other open session; in 'CARE'

Can anybody help with how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].